# VBA loop and deletes rows under condition

Tags: excel, vba

I hope you can help me with my code.

I've been struggling with it for quite some time.

So, the idea is to go through all the sheets that start with "209" and then in column A, delete all the rows except if the cell starts with 4, 5 or 6, if it equals to the sheet name, and if  is equal to 209915.

The problem is even if i select the workbook, I have to go into each sheet and run it, otherwise it just runs for the first sheet,

here's the code I wrote :

```
Sub loopanddelete()

   Dim i As Long
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
   Application.EnableEvents = False

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook

   For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

      If Left(ws.Name, 3) = "209" Then

         For i = ws.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

             If Left(Cells(i, 1), 1) <> "4" And Left(Cells(i, 1), 1) <> "5" And Left(Cells(i, 1), 1) <> "6" And Left(Cells(i, 1), 6) <> ws.Name And Left(Cells(i, 1), 6) <> "209915" Then Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

         Next i
     
     End If
   
  Next ws
    Set wb = Nothing


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 End Sub
```

could you please help ?

thank you in advance

Comment: put `ws.` in front of all range objects: `Cells()` and `Range()` And `Rows()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are stuck in the ActiveSheet because your calls to Cells() and Rows() are not referencing the sheet that is being looped through. When left empty, these will reference the ActiveSheet instead... meaning it never calls on the remaining sheets.

You can either add the sheet to those range objects ('ws.Cells()', 'ws.Rows()'), or you can have the For loop activate the existing sheet ('ws.Activate').

It is likely cleaner code process to just add the worksheet to the range objects being referenced, like so:

```
Sub loopanddelete()

   Dim i As Long
   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
   Application.EnableEvents = False

   Set wb = ThisWorkbook

   For Each ws In wb.Worksheets

      If Left(ws.Name, 3) = "209" Then
         
         For i = ws.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1

             If Left(ws.Cells(i, 1), 1) <> "4" And Left(ws.Cells(i, 1), 1) <> "5" And Left(ws.Cells(i, 1), 1) <> "6" And Left(ws.Cells(i, 1), 6) <> ws.Name And Left(ws.Cells(i, 1), 6) <> "209915" Then ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete

         Next i
     
     End If
   
    Next ws
    
    Set wb = Nothing


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 End Sub
```